# Can I add/update CRM Dynamics plugin assemblies using C# or Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, octopus-deploy

I need to update Dynamics CRM 365 (on-premise) plugins in a repetable way using Octopus Deploy, but to do that I need to find a way to script this update instead of doing it manually.

Is it possible to do it using the CRM SDK or directly using Powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to perform plugin registration with the CRM SDK and/or Powershell.

This can be achieved by creating/updating/deleting certain records (entity logical names are `pluginassembly`, `plugintype`, `sdkmessageprocessingstep`, and `sdkmessageprocessingstepimage`) with suitable attribute values as well as matching references to other plugin-related entities like `sdkmessage` and `sdkmessagefilter`.

At my company, we have developed [our own automatic plugin registration through code](http://delegateas.github.io/Delegate.Daxif/plugin-reg-setup.html), which can be performed by [running a simple script](http://delegateas.github.io/Delegate.Daxif/PluginSyncDev.html). This script can also be run by a build server (like Octopus or VSO), to automatically create/update/delete the plugin registrations in CRM to match those found in our code.

You can check out the source code for it (written in F#) on [our GitHub](https://github.com/delegateas/Daxif/tree/master/src/Delegate.Daxif/Modules/Plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics CRM plugins are part of the CRM Solution. What you are looking for is a way to deploy CRM Solutions.

When planning for deployment decide first if you are going to deploy your solution in managed or unmanaged form. Then decide for a tool. The CRM SDK has a deployment tool. There are also PowerShell scripts available. (See on TechNet: [Administer the deployment using Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531202.aspx) and [Deploy packages using Dynamics CRM Package Deployer and Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647420.aspx).)